# SetWindowsHookEx for WH_KEYBOARD_LL handler PostThreadMessage message not received?

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex

I setup a handler to catch keystrokes for a short time while using a private message loop for the window.   And while it works, if I try the `PostThreadMessage` the window never receives the message?

The callback looked like (I tried other messages to, this one sample was with a private message):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LLKeyboardHookProc(int ncode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) 
{
  if (ncode ==  HC_ACTION) {
    if (wp==WM_KEYDOWN) {
      KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbs=reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lp);
      if (kbs->vkCode==VK_ESCAPE) {
        PostThreadMessage (GetCurrentThreadId(), UWM_MYCLOSEMESSAGE, 0, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  return CallNextHookEx(0, ncode, wp, lp);
}

HHOOK kbhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LLKeyboardHookProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

The message loop for the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window looks like:

```
  while (IsWindow(hwnd)) {
    MSG msg;
    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
      ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
      ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    // let MFC do its idle processing
    LONG lIdle=0;
    while (AfxGetApp()->OnIdle(lIdle++));

    WaitMessage();
  }

  // clean up
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(kbhook);
```

I changed it to use a volatile variable for now to close the window but I'd really like to send it a message.  Using a global HWND wouldn't be thread-safe without locks so didn't want to go that way.

P.S.  I did check the PostThreadMessage result and it was not FALSE (no debug messages when I added them) so it seemed to post it somewhere.

Comment: Never use PostThreadMessage() when you also created a window, something as simple as resizing the window causes the message to get lost.  But, clearly, you don't have any code in the message loop that handles the message.  DispatchMessage() does nothing with it, no window.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PostThreadMessage()` posts a *thread* message to the queue, not a *window* message. Your message loop is ignoring *thread* messages, only dispatching *window* messages.  A window will NEVER see a *thread* message, so you need to handle such messages directly in your message loop instead, eg:

```cpp
MSG msg;
while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
    if (msg.hwnd == NULL && msg.message == UWM_MYCLOSEMESSAGE) { // <-- add this
        // do something...
    }
    else {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

However, as Hans Passant stated in a comment:

> Never use PostThreadMessage() when you also created a window, **something as simple as resizing the window causes the message to get lost**.

Raymond Chen has posted several blog articles on this subject:

[Thread messages are eaten by modal loops](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783)

[Watching thread messages disappear](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050427-10/?p=35763)

[Rescuing thread messages from modal loops via message filters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050428-00/?p=35753)

[Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553)

You could try using a `WH_MSGFILTER` hook, like Raymond demonstrated.  But the best way to solve this is to simply not post a *thread* message at all, post a *window* message instead.  Have your keyboard hook use `PostMessage()` (or even `SendMessage()`) to an `HWND` that your app owns, and then you can handle the message in that window's message procedure.